# Preserving a view on return navigation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying to create a music player application that plays audio files. I've managed to create the player but when I navigate back (or dismiss it), the view state is lost, though the control centre player is still playing the audio. Now when I make any attempts to go back to the player, the view loads all over again and two audios play simultaneously (from different starting points of course). I believe the problem is I'm not preserving the view when dismissing it. One way I thought was to keep track of all changes and load the view with the 'preserved' settings but since this is a music player, there are too many things to keep track of. So my question is:

1. Is there a better strategy to preserve the view state? (I've tried to hide and the screen goes black and I somehow don't get how to use container views)
2. And more importantly, how can I minimize my player and let the user navigate around and allow him/her to return to the player without affecting the experience.

Comment: Where are you navigating back from? Another view, presented how, modally? Pushed into a navigation controller? Is the second view a strong or weak reference of the first? It might make sense to post some code so people can get a sense of the hierarchy.

Comment: You can preserve state using Core Data, but if you haven't used it... there is a little learning curve. As far as the player goes, I would dismiss it in the deinit {} of the viewController or in override func prepareForSegue unless you actually want its state to continue to the next controller. If that is the case then just do a check on the state when you return to the initial viewController and decline acting as you did the first load of the viewController accordingly by not starting the audio, or by removing the previous audio and starting it again.

Comment: @diatrevolo - TabBar Ctrlr >> Navigation Ctlr >> TableView >> Audio Player. I'm trying to preserve the audio player when I go back to the table view / minimize the audio player's view.

Comment: @Sethmr - I'm not using coreData .. So you reckon using some form of a global collection to preserve the state and then resume it? But this would mean I've to keep updating objects like the slider and labels that show the time. Wouldn't there be a jump in the audio when I get back to the view? (As I would have to resume the player and the controls from the state they're in). Would there be another way to sort of minimize the player and resume it?

Comment: Might be a good case for a singleton that contains a global AVAudioPlayer @maaz.

Comment: I have not used Audio in my Applications much, so I haven't been in your shoes. It sounds like a singleton would be appropriate though.

Comment: Okay let me try ... but even in the case I implement a singleton, I still have to preserve the view state ... I wonder how audio apps like spotify etc do it? They can minimize their players and get them back up and running without much hassle to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create and attach a subview that persists and then dismiss the subview from the superview whenever you're done using it.

Comment: could you include more detail so it might help someone else that has the same problem?

Comment: Sure. The solution I got working (almost, as I'm still combating the swift 3 upgrade) was to create a separate xib file with the music player elements and then load the xib as a subview of a superview.

Comment: And yes, the singleton worked for the backend code. So my music player helper was instantiated as a singleton and I used that instance to play or replace it with a new file playing. Also, adding a subview ensures the view is always there and doesn't go away - this approach might eat up some screen real-estate though.